# Given two words and their corresponding pieces-of-speech, how to return them in the order that makes most grammatical sense?

Tags: ruby, sorting, nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

I have an app that creates two randomly generated words. My goal is to return them in the order that makes the most sense grammatically.

Getting their corresponding pieces-of-speech to each word should not be difficult, but my main question is to how to implement the logic to handle the rules. It seems like it would be an absurd number of relational rules given any two pieces of speech. IE, given a noun, a list of rules for which POS goes before or after it, then repeat by making another exhaustive list for each other POS and its relationships to other pieces-of-speech. How even do you structure something like that in an elegant way, if there is no better way to accomplish this?

If a given word can be multiple pieces-of-speech ("duck", "novel", etc), is there an ideal way to handle that?

I'm aware english is complicated and there will always be exceptions, but a "best guess" would be satisfactory.

Comment: I doubt that you are going to get much help here. There is no "right answer" to your question and it calls for opinions, which may rule it [out-of-bounds for SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Also, what do you mean "grammatical" for a pair of words? Is "eat an" a grammatical pair of words (since "eat an omelette" is a grammatical sentence)? And what does it have to do with [tag:sorting] and [tag:ruby]?

Comment: Given the goals of the program, "eat an" would be considered more correct than "an eat", yes. It doesn't make a ton of sense there, but for other cases it's quite clear which is the "correct" order:

"adjective" "noun" (big car, for example, not "car big")